# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method is not being called

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a fragment and a service , I want to update UI (listview) of Fragment from service after performing a task so I created a BroadcastReceiver , but onReceive method is not being called.Please suggest.

here is my code :
MyReciever :

```
 public class Myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("TAG" , "onrecive::");
                refreshView();
            }

        }
```

onREsume/onPause of fragment :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, tag + " onResume() called");
    Log.d("TAG" , "nibha :: test on resume " +DeliveryOrder.isSyncDone );

    getActivity().registerReceiver(myrec,
            new IntentFilter("com.Mediapp."+tag+".SYNC_FINISH"));

    mDOListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, tag + " onResume() ended");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, tag + " onPause called");
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(myrec);
    Log.d(TAG, tag + " onPause ended");
}
```

onService:

```
Log.d("TAG" , "nibha :: test " +DeliveryOrder.isSyncDone );
            Intent in= new Intent();
            in.setAction("com.Mediapp."+tag+".SYNC_FINISH");
            sendBroadcast(in);
            Log.d("nibha", "onHandleIntent: sending broadcast");
```

Comment: Did you register your broadcast receiver?

Comment: yes on onResume method

Comment: Try to add default category for intent you use for `sendBroadcast` function

Comment: why don't you use a bound service?

Answer (score 0):

Register `BroadcastReceiver` in Android Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".Myreceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In `onResume()` method, save a boolean value in `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();

e.putBoolean("action_performed", true);
e.commit();
```

Now in `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` check whether **action_performed** is true or not. If it is then do what you want to.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TAG" , "onrecive::");

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean actionDone = settings.getBoolean("action_performed", false);

    if(actionDone) {
        refreshView();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have registered it on onResume method

Comment: @NibhaJain You should register your receiver in `onStart()` not in `onResume()` and if you want to destroy, unregister it in `onStop()`.

Comment: I want to call onReceive method on resuming to the fragment after a particular action

Comment: @NibhaJain You should register `BroadcastReceiver` in AndroidManifest, in `onResume()` method set a boolean value to `true` and check boolean state in `onReceive` method. **See my updated answer**.

Comment: no , but I solved the issue .. the problem was my broadcast was getting unregister at onPause method at the time of performing task from service